# Manual install vs conda install tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, anaconda, linux

Asking mainly for Ubuntu 16.04/18.04.
What's the difference between installing CUDA and cuDNN together with tensorflow-gpu in conda (`conda install tensorflow-gpu`), and installing it all by hand and then using pip?
Does it mean CUDA and cuDNN are only available in the environment where `conda install tensorflow-gpu` was invoked?
Also, why do some people use the `-c` flag when installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all Cuda and CuDnn libraries are included with packages from Anaconda Cloud according to this guy:  https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Install-CUDA-10-together-with-9-2-on-Ubuntu-18-04-with-support-for-NVIDIA-20XX-Turing-GPUs-1236/

> You do NOT need to install CUDA 10 if; You are a developer working
>   with CUDA 9.x or earlier in your code base and there are no compelling
>   new features that you want to risk breaking your application to try.
>   See the release notes. You are working with Python machine learning
>   frameworks AND using Anaconda Python. Most of the frameworks have
>   up-to-date builds available from Anaconda Cloud that include the
>   needed CUDA libraries i.e. you don't have to install anything outside
>   of the package you want. You are using GPU accelerated software
>   packages that only depend on CUDA run-time support from the display
>   driver. That includes most "ready to use" or commercial software. You
>   don't know what CUDA is. In that case then, well, thanks for reading
>   my post. I hope you enjoy it and learn something from it.

Check out this advice:  https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc

He says just create a conda env like `conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu` where `tf_gpu` is the env name and `tensorflow-gpu` is to include cuda and cudnn in that env.  Breaking it down into separate commands, it looks like:

```
conda create --name tf_gpu
activate tf_gpu
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```